# Plotting a correlation matrix with GNUPlot

Tags: matrix, gnuplot, octave, correlation

I would like to know how to plot a correlation matrix similar to the example below using GNUPlot (possibly from Octave, if that makes answers easier, but that's really not necessary):

[image: Correlation matrix example]

The input is a square matrix of values between 0 and 1. The output should be a square grid where the color or the `x,y` square is given by the value in the `x`th row and `y`th column. (Typically, there are only ones on the diagonal and a diagonal symmetry in the input, but that doesn't change anything to the problem.)

Optionally I would also love to know how to specify the color map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using splot

If you have the data in ASCII format then you can plot the matrix with

```
set pm3d map
splot "Data.csv" matrix
```

where `"Data.csv"` is the path to the data file.
Details about plotting matrices as well as 3D-plots are available [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-33800045.1.4) and [there](http://web.archive.org/web/20100904042958/http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/plotpm3d-e.html).

In order to change the color settings you need to specify a new palette. To specify a new palette for different color schemes, take a look at [this](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-21800043.50) documentation. Furthermore tutorials about setting new palettes can be found [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100904042958/http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/plotpm3d2-e.html).

#### Using plot

Another way of doing it is:

```
plot "Data.csv" matrix with image
```

If the data is binary, the scan direction can be further controlled with `flipx`, `center` and `rotate`.